# FB Graph API issue in fetching adeducationschool, adeducationmajor, adworkemployer, adworkposition

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

API issue in fetching adeducationschool, adeducationmajor, adworkemployer, adworkposition

I am getting empty data for this endpoint

https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/search?type=adeducationschool&q=ha&access_token=
https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/search?type=adeducationmajor&q=ph&access_token=
https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/search?type=adworkemployer&q=mic&access_token=
https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/search?type=adworkposition&q=Business Analyst&access_token=

No matter what query is used

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/reference/targeting-search/

I have been trying this. May I know what exactly is the problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe they have a minimum length for the search parameter. With `q=ha` I get no results either, `q=har` gives me `Harvard Business School Online` as a result. `q=harv` gives me three additional "Harveys". (Why those did not show up for `har` already, you'd have to ask Facebook.)

Comment: for me `q=har` gives nothing

Comment: Did for me, but could be that the results differ, based on whose access token is used.

Comment: I guess so, For me nothing appears for these, I tried with many targets. Anyways thanks for trying.